# Time to turn 180 degrees

Tags: vb.net

I have a space ship, and am wanting to calculate how long it takes to turn `180` degrees. This is my current code to turn the ship:

```
.msngFacingDegrees = .msngFacingDegrees + .ROTATION_RATE * TV.TimeElapsed
```

My current `.ROTATION_RATE` is `0.15`, but it will change.

I have tried:

```
Math.Ceiling(.ROTATION_RATE * TV.TimeElapsed / 180)
```

But always get an answer of `1`. Please help.

Comment: What are the data types you're using?

Comment: Try this: `Math.Ceiling(.ROTATION_RATE * TV.TimeElapsed / 180.0)` ... notice the `.0` added to the hardcoded value of 180. 180 is alone is treated as an integer which skews your decimal calculation to int...

Comment: Why are you including TV.TimeElapsed in your calculation?  Isn't this the unknown that you're trying to solve for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain why you get 1 all the time:

Math.Ceiling simply rounds up to the next integer, so your sum contents must always be < 1.

Rearranging your sum gives `TV.TimeElapsed = 180 * (1/.ROTATION_Rate)`. With a `ROTATION_Rate` of 0.15 we know that TV.TimeElapsed needs to reach 1200 before your overall function returns > 1.

Is it possible that you're always looking at elapsed times less than this threshold?

Going further to suggest what your sum should be is harder - Its not completely clear without more context.

Comment: Even if I change the code to: Math.Ceiling(.ROTATION_RATE / 180.0), I still only get 1. Is there a better way to calculate how long it takes to rotate 180 degrees?

Comment: You have it flipped - Jon suggested Math.Ceiling(180.0 / RotationRate).  This is simple algebra.